# What is the difference(s) between $(a,\infty)$ and $(a,\infty]$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am studying H. L. Royden's Real Analysis which includes some introduction to Measure Theory; and I encountered $(a,\infty]$ instead of $(a,\infty)$ for the first time!

What is the difference(s) between $(a,\infty)$ and $(a,\infty]$?

Comment: It depends on author to author. They mean same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(a,\infty)=&\,\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,x>a\},\\
(a,\infty]=&\,\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,x>a\}\cup\{\infty\}.
\end{align*}
The latter set includes an extra point termed “positive infinity.” Note that it is *not* a real number, but in certain areas of mathematics, especially in measure theory, it is useful to extend $\mathbb R$ by this single point to denote a quantity that is greater than all conceivable real numbers. With treating $\infty$ as though it were actually a number satisfying the property $\infty>x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, the interval notation becomes quite intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times these two mean the same thing, but it is important to consider the superset of which this is an interval. Sometimes, (especially in measure theory, which is why I mention it) it is useful to work in the extended reals, which includes a point at $\infty$, so $(a,\infty)$ means every number greater than $a$ accept infinity and $(a,\infty]$ would, as the notation suggests, include that point.